# optimal sorting

Tags: algorithms, extremal-combinatorics

I got a solution to the following question, but am unable to provide a proof.

Given 25 distinct integers, one can sort them 5 at a time. What is the least number of sorting to obtain the smallest 3 numbers?

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution with 7 sorts. If we can show that 6 sorts do not suffice to find the smallest 3 numbers, we are done.

When looking for the smallest number one can eliminate 4 numbers with each sort (of 5 numbers). So we need 6 sorts to eliminate 24 numbers to eventually find the smallest number out of 25. Now we will show that one cannot avoid having two candidates for the second smallest number after 6 sorts.

- candidate 1: The second smallest of the 6th sort is a candidate for the second smallest number in total. (For some strategies you can be lucky and be sure that this is the second smallest number; e.g. if you always take the smallest number of a sort into the next sort and then it happens that the smallest number of the 5th sort is second in the 6th sort. But one cannot force this.)
- (potential) candidate 2: As mentioned under "candidate 1" such a candidate 2 for the second smallest number need not exist. But for each strategy an order of how the numbers go into the sorts can be constructed, s.t. such a candidate 2 exists. Since a strategy must work in all cases, only one such construction of number ordering suffices to reject it. In brief the possibility of a second candidate for the second smallest number can be argued as follows: Among the numbers of the 6th sort there will be the smallest number of the 5th sort. Now if this number turns out smallest in the 6th sort (note that any number in the 6th sort could be the smallest one because in the first 5 sorts only 20 numbers could be eliminated from being the smallest one), the second smallest number of the 5th sort is also a candidate for the overall second smallest number.

So we need at least a 7th sort to find the second smallest number (under any order of how the numbers are put into the sorts for a given strategy) and hence also to find the smallest 3 numbers.

**Appendix**:
Let us for example show such problematic number orderings for two specific strategies. The order of how the numbers go into the sorts must be such that the smallest number of the 5th sort is the overall smallest number (and thus the second smallest number of the 5th sort will be the "candidate 2" for the overall second smallest number). Without loss of generality we can assume that the numbers to sort are 1,2,...25.

**Strategy 1**: The smallest number of each sort goes into the next sort.

When the numbers are in the following, almost reverse, order 25,24,...8,7,2,1,6,5,4,3 and taken one after the other as needed we get the following sorts:

```
1. 25,24,23,22,21 -> 21,22,23,24,25
1. 21,20,19,18,17 -> 17,18,19,20,21
1. 17,16,15,14,13 -> 13,14,15,16,17
1. 13,12,11,10, 9 ->  9,10,11,12,13
1.  9, 8, 7, 2, 1 ->  1, 2, 7, 8, 9
1.  1, 6, 5, 4, 3 ->  1, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

From the sorts we only now `1 < 2` and `1 < 3`. So both 2 and 3 could be the second smallest number.

**Strategy 2** (the one solving the original question): group the numbers by 5 and send these groups into the first 5 sorts. Then take the smallest numbers of the first 5 sorts and put them into the 6th sort.

When the numbers are in the following almost strict ascending order 6,7,...25,1,2,...5 and taken one after the other as needed we get the following sorts:

```
1.  6, 7, 8, 9,10 ->  6, 7, 8, 9,10
2. 11,12,13,14,15 -> 11,12,13,14,15
3. 16,17,18,19,20 -> 16,17,18,19,20
4. 21,22,23,24,25 -> 21,22,23,24,25
5.  1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ->  1, 2, 3, 4, 5
6.  1, 6,11,16,21 ->  1, 6,11,16,21
```

After the 6th sort we only know `1 < 2` and `1 < 6`, so both 2 and 6 could be the second smallest number.

Like done for these 2 strategies it is possible (by the above proof) to generate an order of how the numbers go into the sorts such that after the 6th sort both the second smallest number of the 5th sort and the second smallest number of the 6th sort are candidates for the overall second smallest number.

Comment: I do not understand what "second sort" refers to in "none of the eliminated numbers can be in a second sort". The second sort eliminates 4 numbers to find the smallest number, if it is disjoint from the members of the first sort. Could you explain?

Comment: @Hans: "second sort" refers not to the second of the $6$ sorts you perform in all, but to a sort in which an eliminated number appears for the second time.

Comment: For completeness (perhaps not for the OP, who knows a solution, but for the benefit of other readers), here's a solution with $7$ sorts: Sort $5$ disjoint groups of $5$; then sort the $5$ winners. That leaves one number known to be the smallest of all, and $5$ numbers that could potentially be the second or third smallest; sorting those $5$ completes the task.

Comment: @joriki I wanted to leave the honor of revealing the answer to Hans :-) btw: what do you mean with 'OP'?

Comment: @joriki Basically joriki is right, but I just realized that my explanation with "not in a second sort" is imprecise since the minima of the first 5 sorts can only be eliminated with an additional sort. I will try to fix this.

Comment: @coproc: how does "any of the eliminated numbers could be the second smallest one" lead to any first 6 sorts does not provide enough information to find the second and third smallest numbers?

Comment: @coproc: OP: original post(er)

Comment: @coproc: It's also not right that "any of the eliminated numbers could be the second smallest one" -- in fact in the solution with $7$ sorts, after $6$ sorts only two numbers can be the second smallest one.

Comment: @joriki you are right, I have just stumbled accross that and tried to fix the proof. It suffices to have two candidates for the second smallest one after 6 sorts. And not even that needs to be the case - but you cannot force it!

Comment: @coproc: In your answer regarding candidate 2, the statement "among the numbers of the 6th sort there will be the smallest number of the 5th sort" does not seem to be clear. 5th sort should not be any more special than the first 4 sorts. Candidate 2 should be the second smallest number in the sort that is amongst the first 5 sorts and associated with the overall smallest number. That sort is not necessarily the 5th sort, unless you relabel that sort as the 5th, but you might as well label it the first.

Comment: @Hans 1) if you choose the strategy that the smallest element of a sort goes into the next sort then the elements chosen for the 5th sort depend on the previous sorts - but not the other way around. And hence the 5th sort is special, because no matter which (optimal) strategy for finding the smallest number you choose the smallest number of the 5th sort will always be in the 6th sort. This does not hold for the first 4 sorts. 2) Even if you choose a strategy with a priori determination of which numbers go into which sort it should be clear what the "smallest number of the 5th sort" means.

Comment: @Hans ... 3) When you say that candidate 2 is not necessarily from the 5th sort: can you come up with an example where candidate 2 cannot be from the 5th sort? (from my understanding: no; but let's check that.)

Comment: @coproc: But I may choose strategies where some of the first 5 sorts does not depend on its previous sorts. "This does not hold for the first 4 sorts" is then incorrect. Indeed, we both know the first 5 sorts of the optimal strategy is to sort 5 disjoint 5-number sets and therefore independent and there is no guarantee which sort the second smallest number land. In fact the second candidate can only be in the sort that has the overall smallest number. But that sort can well be one of any of the first 5 and not only the 5th sort.

Comment: @Hans I tried to give a proof that shows that all strategies fail to find the second smallest number after 6 sorts in *all* cases (meaning: also if you are not lucky). Hence I can only rely on the smallest number of the 5th sort. This one will be in the 6th sort no matter what strategy you choose and how you number the first 5 sorts. Now concerning "candidate 2": after the 6th sort we know what numbers are candidates for the second smallest number. For some strategies it can even happen that - if you are lucky! - there is only one candidate for the second smallest number left!

Comment: @Hans Let's try it this way: for any strategy of 6 sorts to hunt for the two smallest numbers an order of the numbers can be found (how they are put into the sorts) such that the second smallest number of the 5th sort could also be the second smallest number. So no strategy can avoid having this (potential) "candidate 2". You can try to come up with a different proof of a (potential) "candidate 2". But I guess such a proof will be longer or fail to handle that we are only having a potential "candidate 2".

Comment: @coproc:"to give a proof that shows that all strategies fail to find the second smallest number after 6 sorts in all cases (meaning: also if you are not lucky)." is exactly what I am after. You can not rule out the second smallest numbers of the first 4 sorts are candidate 2. But that is easy to determine after 6th sort. Once it is determined which is the overall smallest number and which  sort, say $i$'th, amongst the first 5 sorts is associated with that overall smallest number, the second smallest number of the i'th sort is candidate 2. My point is $i\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, not necessarily $5$.

Comment: @coproc: to recap, whether $i$ has to be $5$ or any of 1 to 5 is the only point of disagreement. I agree with the rest of your proof.

Comment: @Hans you are missing a subtle but important point in the proof. You are also after a proof for all strategies. So let's take the strategy of always taking the smallest number of a sort into the next sort. When considering all possible outcomes of the 6th sort, there are outcomes where no such *i* (i.e. candidate 2) exists. But the proof still works! Maybe carefully reading my comment starting with "Let's try it this way" helps. Reasoning about all strategies and all possible orders the numbers can come in is demanding.

Comment: @Hans I really like this problem, many thanks for posting it. But this is my last comment on it, sorry. Good luck!

Comment: @coproc: I am sorry that you would not want to discuss. However, your statement "let's take the strategy of always taking the smallest number of a sort into the next sort." takes a special strategy, exactly violating your own admonition that the proof should work for all strategies. This is not a contrived point, because in fact, the optimal strategy does NOT "take the smallest number of a sort into the next sort" and is thus not covered by your proof regarding candidate 2. So your proof is NOT valid only by that point. It would have been valid had you not specialized the 5th sort.

Comment: @Hans confusion 1: In my comment "let's take the strategy of always taking the smallest number ..." I wanted to show you that my proof *also* works for this strategy whereas your observations/considerations do not work for this strategy. confusion 2: after the 6th sort you may know that the smallest number of the 5th sort cannot be the second smallest number, but it *can* happen. This is the problem. A proof must not only take care of all strategies but also of all possible outcomes - in the appropriate way.

Comment: @Hans You seem to insist that my proof does not work for - what you call - "optimal strategy", but rethink it: it does! After choosing a strategy you cannot influence the result of the sorts any more. You cannot avoid having the smallest number of the 5th sort as candidate for the second smallest number - although it need not happen. But we are looking for a strategy that works in any case (i.e. with any order the numbers go into the sorts). And it suffices to have one counterexample (of an order how the numbers go into the sort) to reject a strategy. My proof tries to take the shortest path.